# How to filter a calendar events in list view based on moth and weak view in calendar view?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, custom-web-parts

I need to filter a Calendar list view based on month and week view, I mean I will add calendar view web part first then I will add my custom web part to show the list view, Think is list view need to be filtered based on the calendar view.

[image]

while switching the month in calendar view, List of events needs to be filtered based on month and week choosing in the calendar view. I am not sure how to achieve this, Please suggest me some idea to achieve this.